# How to override property type of a global interface?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

How to override property type of a global interface, like Array interface:
i want to override `find` function type deceleration

i tried to use file.d.ts and create Array interface and set my own `find` function type... but as i expected it will create an alias for `find`

Comment: You can definitely merge in another call signature for `find()` but without a [mre] I wouldn’t know how to show you.  What others call signature would you like to support and why?  Are you thinking of actually changing how `Array.prototype.find` is *implemented*? If so that’s one of those Very Bad Ideas and any answer should tell you not to do that.  Please [edit] the question with a reproducible example of what you’re trying to do and how it’s intended to work.

Comment: Check if this helps you: 
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-array-extend